# AngularJS code elements are displayed in the HTML UI before getting the API response

Tags: html, angularjs-1.6

I'm using [Angularjs](https://angularjs.org/) and `HTML5`. I have a page where some elements depends on [Angularjs](https://angularjs.org/) variable.
For example in my HTML code I have:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 top-buffer">
    <div class="info-box">
        <div data-ng-bind-html="statusClass"></div>
        <div class="info-box-content">
            <span class="info-box-text">Status</span> <span
                class="info-box-number">{{statusName}}</span>
        </div>
        <!-- /.info-box-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.info-box -->
</div>
```

or ng-show on entire div

```
<div data-ng-show="isBusy" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
```

and

```
<div data-ng-show="!isBusy" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
```

so Ione is hidden and one is shown.

`statusName` and `statusClass`, like `isBusy` and all other variables, are retrieved from [Angularjs](https://angularjs.org/) http call so for one second my page appears different.
How can I avoid this behavior? I thought if it was possible to load this variable before page load, but for the data-ng-bind-html?

Comment: Use `ng-cloak`? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `ng-cloak` will solve the issue in your case i think.

> The ngCloak directive is used to prevent the AngularJS html template
>   from being briefly displayed by the browser in its raw (uncompiled)
>   form while your application is loading. Use this directive to avoid
>   the undesirable flicker effect caused by the html template display. 
>   https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak

So what you could do is call the `ng-cloak` directive on the element you want to wait rendering before the page has been loaded.

```
<div ng-show="isBusy" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3" ng-cloak>
```

---

### UPDATE (arccording to given [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/krsz9/294/)):

---

`ng-show` shows or hides the given HTML element based on the expression provided.

> The ngShow directive shows or hides the given HTML element based on
>   the expression provided to the ngShow attribute.
>
> https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow

You render two buttons. Both button have the same expression, except one button checks if the expression is `true` while the other checks  if the expression is `false`

```
<!-- True -->
<button ng-show="clickedStartButton" ng-cloak>{{text}}</button>

<!-- False -->
<button ng-show="!clickedStartButton" ng-cloak>{{text2}}</button>
```

The `ng-show="!clickedStartButton"` will allways return `false` at start, because no value has been assigned to it yet. So this `button` will allways render. Except of course when you do `$scope.clickedStartButton = true`. But then

```
<button ng-show="clickedStartButton" ng-cloak>{{text}}</button>
```

will be rendered without the `{{text}}` property.

You can do following to avoid it. Check if `{{text2}}` isset. If not, then `hide` else `show`

```
<button ng-if="!clickedStartButton && text2" ng-cloak>{{text2}}</button>
```

---

### **DEMO**

```js
var app=angular.module('timerApp', []);
app.controller('timerController', ['$scope', '$interval', '$timeout', function ($scope, $interval, $timeout) {
  $timeout(function() {$scope.text="PROVA"; $scope.text2="PROVA2"; $scope.clickedStartButton=true; }, 2000);
   
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
Will be rendered after 2 seconds

<div ng-app="timerApp" ng-controller="timerController">
    <button ng-if="clickedStartButton" ng-cloak>{{text}}</button>
    <button ng-if="!clickedStartButton && text2" ng-cloak>{{text2}}</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried ng-cloak like your example but it doesn't work, still show the element before variable is ready. I have adiv with ng-show="isBusy" and one with ng-show="!isBusy"

Comment: Can you make a fiddle or plunkr? Would be really helpfull.

Comment: Also, put `ng-cloak` also on the `ng-bind-html` `div`. You can put `ng-cloak` on all elements which are rendering data from angular.

Comment: on `data-ng-bind-html` seems to work but on ng-show it still show the div

Comment: Try to change `ng-show` to `ng-if`. This basicly does the same. `ng-if` clones the `element` then append (renders) when statement is `true` or `false`. If `false`, it removes the element from the `dom` tree.

Comment: It's the same, maybe the problem is with the not condition. Here https://jsfiddle.net/krsz9/294/ you can see that the button appears before variable is setted. I can create another opposite variable....

Comment: I know the issue, i will update my awnser soon. Ive to go for 15 min now. When back ill update it.